# PayPal API - sandbox on live server payment->create returns false

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated PayPal on my website. I'm using paypal sandbox for processing payments and that works fine on my local machine. But when I uploaded it on my live server it didn't work.

I'm using sandbox mode on live server too and when someone clicks on 'Pay' button he gets an error message. Instead of that he should be redirected to PayPal checkout page.

This line of code returns **false** for some reason, and I'm passing API credentials (ApiContext class with client id and secret)

```
$pay = $this->payment->create(parent::getAuth());
```

I don't understand what went wrong, I don't get an exception or any other error message, so I can't figure it out what's going on. Everything seems all right (payer, item, details, amount classes etc), the only different thing between the site on my local machine and this one on the live server is that I have created new paypal app for my live website and I passed right api credentials for that app.

Some other info:

I'm using my person paypal account in developer paypal to create paypal app and my real account isn't business account but I don't know if that matters for sandbox testing, because it works in localhost.

You can check my website [HERE](http://www.mishke.co.nf)

> Note: I created this site just to improve my developer skills! I or anyone else will not
>   use this for production.

Comment: you have to create and use a business sandbox account

Comment: another thing, after i enter all parameters your payment form still give me "Unesite validne podatke."

Comment: So far I have been using my real personal account for creating paypal app and that worked on my local machine (wamp). So, If I want to use sandbox on liver server I need real business paypal account and then I can create paypal app for live server, even it is only for testing purposes

Comment: that is a message stored in a session if $pay variable is false

Comment: @bfahmi Did I understand you correctly? I need a business PayPal account and then I can create paypal app and use it for sandbox testing?